# Angular js wait for data before return

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I have an angular service where I make an http post call. Also, some constant values are set there. In the end I use return to send these data to the controller, do some logic and display them in a view.

The service code:

```
var apiurl = 'myurl';
  var apidata = {data: 'mydata'};
  var myDataPromise = httppostrequest($http, apiurl, apidata);

    myDataPromise.then(function(result) {
        service.datas = result;
        console.log("data.name"+result);
    });
    return service;
```

The httppostrequest function:

```
function httppostrequest($http, apiurl, apidata){
    return $http({
        method : "POST",
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        url: apiurl,
        data: JSON.stringify(apidata),
        timeout: 5000
    });
}
```

The request is successful and returns the data. The problem is that the line

**return service;**

is executed before the data from the request are assigned to the service variable. Therefore the data from the post request are not even passed to the controller.

I have worked with node js, where there are ways and tools to avoid the asynchronous nature when needed. With angularjs I don't get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You described perfectly what is happening. 
So my suggestion is to init the value of `datas` inside the service to an empty value (object, array, or whatever it will be after fetched the promise), associate the promise to the service, and simply move the promise resolution where you really need to manipulate that data. So inside your service:

```
var apiurl = 'myurl';
var apidata = {data: 'mydata'};
service.datas = []; // if it will be an array for example
service.myDataPromise = httppostrequest($http, apiurl, apidata);

return service;
```

And then wherever you need it, just inject your service and do:

```
myService.myDataPromise.then(function(result) {
  myService.datas = result;
  console.log("data.name"+result);
});
```

Comment: In case I misunderstand, are you suggesting that I inject the service somewhere else (ex. the controller)?

Comment: yep exactly, you got it

Comment: Thanks, that actually worked. And I think I also understood the logic of it.

Answer (score 1):

Whatever return you have you will have to put it inside the success method. Otherwise you will see that issue.

You can do something like this:

```
 var data = {} //your data
 var promiseURLMetaData = HttpService.httpPost("parseUrlMetadata", data);
 promiseURLMetaData.then(function (response) {
     var urlMetaData = response.data;
     return urlMetaData;
  })
 .catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Something went terribly wrong while trying to get URL Meta Data.");
 });
```

Comment: Tried that. Now nothing gets returned, although the then block is executed successfully. Also there is no error (i changed the log in the catch block so that it displays errors)

Comment: Is that service an angular service?

Comment: @AmeliaGrimaldi What you can do is have a service, then add setters and getters for the data. Then once you get the data from the http call add it through the setter and then when you access the data, access it through the getter. That is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

Return your service inside the result function.

```
var apiurl = 'myurl';
var apidata = {data: 'mydata'};
var myDataPromise = httppostrequest($http, apiurl, apidata);

    myDataPromise.then(function(result) {
        service.datas = result;
        console.log("data.name"+result);
        return service;
    });
```